# How can I get the absolute path of the preference file for a particular plugin in eclipse plugin development?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to read the absolute path of the preference file for a particular plugin which is generally stored at:

```
Platform.getLocation() + "\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\myPlugin.prefs"
```

Is there any way to get it directly somehow using eclipse provided Apis instead of hard-coding the 2nd part of the path?

Comment: Do you actually want the path or do you just want to access the preferences?

Comment: I want the absolute path of the file.

Comment: If you look at the `InstancePreferences` class there's code in there that will let you build the path dynamically, but it would mean accessing some Eclipse internal classes (particularly `MetaDataKeeper.getMetaArea().getStateLocation()`)

Comment: @NickWilson, Thanks for the input I tried it but it gives the location of the folder of myPlugin inside "\.metadata\.plugins\" which is basically same as Platform.getStateLoaction(). I want some api which can give me the absolute path till "\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\" atleast

Comment: The method I mentioned was just for the base path. `InstancePreferences.getLocation()` works out the full path but is a protected method. You'd need to do the same things it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give the correct location:

```java
Bundle rt = Platform.getBundle(IPreferencesConstants.RUNTIME_NAME);

IPath path = Platform.getStateLocation(rt).append(".settings").append("myPlugin").addFileExtension("prefs");
```

The actual location calculation is in `org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences`

Comment: Thanks, it looks like we don't have any exposed api to do it. Then your solution should be the best way to do it as it will have only one hard-coded string ".settings".